# Agrupar fechas por semana en pandas (pd.PeriodIndex) indicando el domingo como primer dia de la semana

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

En un data frame tengo una columna con las fechas, necesitamos agrupar las fechas por semana para algunas consultas, el metodo pd.PeriodIndex lo hace perfectamente pero por defecto toma como primer dia de la semana el lunes, como se le puede indicar que el primer dia de la semana sea el domingo, agrupando las fechas en semanas de Domingo a Sabado.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

inicio = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
fin = dt.datetime(2020,12,31)

lista = pd.date_range(inicio, fin, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Fecha'] = lista

df['Semana'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Fecha'], freq='W')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con freq=**'W-SAT'**:

```
df['Semana2'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Fecha'], freq='W-SAT')
```

algunas filas:

```
         Fecha                 Semana                 Semana2
0   2020-01-01  2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-12-29/2020-01-04
1   2020-01-02  2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-12-29/2020-01-04
2   2020-01-03  2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-12-29/2020-01-04
3   2020-01-04  2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2019-12-29/2020-01-04
4   2020-01-05  2019-12-30/2020-01-05   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
5   2020-01-06  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
6   2020-01-07  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
7   2020-01-08  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
8   2020-01-09  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
9   2020-01-10  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
10  2020-01-11  2020-01-06/2020-01-12   2020-01-05/2020-01-11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Dado un mes y año correspondiente, entrega un diccionario con las fechas de inicio y final de cada semana del mes.
import pandas as pd
semana = {"1": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0},
         "2": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0},
         "3": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0},
         "4": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0},
         "5": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0},
         "6": {"start_day":0, "end_day":0}
         }
mes = pd.Period('2022-12')
start_day =  mes.start_time
end_day = mes.end_time
week = pd.date_range(str(mes), periods = dias_mes)
i =1
for day in week:
    #print('{}-{}\t{}'.format(day.day_of_week, day.day_name(), day.date()))
    semana["1"]["start_day"] = start_day.date()
    if day.day_of_week == 0:
        semana[str(i)]["start_day"] = day.date()
    if day.day_of_week == 6:
        semana[str(i)]["end_day"] = day.date()
        i+=1
semana[str(i)]["end_day"] = end_day.date()
semana
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola Gabo...123, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, te sugiero que elimines o modifiques tu respuesta, ya que la misma no es correcta, por otro lado, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.